# remove values within an array user meta

Tags: php

hello I save the values as here:
[Add value to usermeta without removing previous values?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/305254/add-value-to-usermeta-without-removing-previous-values/305255#305255)

```php
$email_suscriptor = $_POST['cancelsus'];

$dismissed = array_filter( explode( ',', (string) get_user_meta( $vendor_id, 'emails_suscriptores13', true ) ) );

if ( ! in_array( $email_suscriptor, $dismissed ) ) {
    $dismissed[] = $emailsus;
 $dismissed =  implode(",", $dismissed);
   update_user_meta( $vendor_id, 'emails_suscriptores13', $dismissed );
}
```

Result:

```
 $list_emails= get_user_meta( $vendor_id, 'emails_suscriptores13', true );

echo $list_emails;
```

so it looks:

```
1@gmail.com,2@hotmail.com,3@gmail.com
```

Users send their emails from a subscription form and I can save them with this code but I can't delete their emails (values within the user meta)

the problem is that I can't delete them

in my role I save emails from subscribing users so I need to be able to delete an email when someone wants to do it

try delete_user_meta, using the same code but it doesn't work

Don't work:

```
$cancelsus = $_GET['cancelsus'];

if (isset($cancelsus)) {

$dismissed = array_filter( explode( ',', (string) get_user_meta( $vendor_id, 'emails_suscriptores13', true ) ) );

if ( ! in_array( $cancelsus, $dismissed ) ) {
 $dismissed[] = $cancelsus;
 $dismissed =  implode(",", $dismissed);

   delete_user_meta( $vendor_id, 'emails_suscriptores13', $dismissed );
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried?

Comment: yes, i tried this:

$dismissed [] = $emailsus;
  $dismissed = implode (",", $dismissed);
    delete_user_meta ($vendor_id, 'emails_subscribers13', $dismissed);

just change update to delete

Comment: So you're trying to delete a value from an array of user_meta?  The value is an array, and you want to remove one value from the array?

Comment: What I am trying to remove is an email (value) inside an array of user_meta. As I try to explain, I have a simple form where users send their email and so I save those emails within the user_meta array to subscribe. But then I have to remove them when they want to unsubscribe and I don't understand how to remove a value. I will update my question for a better understanding